# Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, codeigniter

alguien sabe porque me sale  este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en esta funcion:

```
function agregar_empresas_usuarios($id_empresas,$id_usuario){

        $this->db->select("r.id_rol");//ver si el usuario es admin o no
        $this->db->from("colegiosam_usuarios u");
        $this->db->join("colegiosam_roles r","r.id_rol = u.FK_id_rol");
        $this->db->where("u.id_usuario = $id_usuario");
        $rol_user = $this->db->get()->result();

        if($rol_user[0]->id_rol == ROLE_ADMIN){//si es admin, insertar un id_empresa_usuario por cada usuario
            $this->db->select("id_empresa");
            $this->db->from("empresas");
            $id_empresas = $this->db->get();

            foreach($id_empresas->result() as $id_empresa){
                $datos['id_empresa'] = $id_empresa;
                $datos['id_usuario'] = $id_usuario;
                $datos['status'] = 1;
                $this->db->insert('usuario_empresa',$datos);
                unset($datos);
            }
        }
        else{
            foreach($id_empresas as $id_empresa){
                $datos['id_empresa'] = $id_empresa;
                $datos['id_usuario'] = $id_usuario;
                $datos['status'] = 1;
                $this->db->insert('usuario_empresa',$datos);
                unset($datos);
            }
        }
    }
```

Les agradeceria mucho su ayuda, gracias.

PD: los parametros si tienen valores.

Comment: cuál es la linea 1477?

Comment: eso es del driver del codeigniter, al solucionar el problema de abajo se soluciona el de arriba

Comment: @Sr1871 esa es una linea dentro de las clases que ya trae por defecto Codeigniter, en todo caso se debería de pregunatr caul es la linea 691.

Comment: un usuario pude tener muchas empresas y una empresa la pueden tener muchos usuarios? y los siguienetes tipos de datos estan correctos `(array) $id_empresas,(int) $id_usuario`

Comment: Solo estas pasando el id del usuario y el estatus, pero te falta el id de la empresa, verifica que el id de la empresa contenga algo, por eso te da el error.